# Lining up divs side by side and div exceeding container div

Tags: html, css

I need your help,

My problem is two fold, firstly BoxB exceeds the height of its main (parent) box, and secondly, I can't seem to be able to line up BoxB and BoxC neatly, side by side of each other.

Here is a quick screenshot:

[image]

```css
* {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
#main {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#boxA {
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180,180,180);
}
#boxB {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}
#boxC {
    background: rgb(240,240,240);
    height: 100%;
    width: 545px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float:left;

}
```

```html
<div id="main">

    <div id="boxA">Application Title</div>

    <div id="boxB"></div>

    <div id="boxC"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: You're not properly closing your divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as pointed out you didn't close the `DIVs` properly. As for the other 2 issues. If you remove the floats and use `display: inline-block` the divs will be on same line. Also if you make content `box-sizing: border-box;` this will help because it keeps borders/padding as a part of the total width/height of elements. And I suggest if you know the main content will always be `600px` in height as you defined in CSS you should just give the top div a set height and give remaining height to bottom two divs as well.

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="boxA">Application Title</div>
    <div id="boxB"></div>
    <div id="boxC"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 9pt;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#main {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#boxA {
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180,180,180);
    height: 25px;
}
#boxB {
    height: 575px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
#boxC {
    background: rgb(240,240,240);
    height: 575px;
    width: 545px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hpuywg42/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `#boxC` not being in the right place is easier to solve. This:

```
<div id="boxB"><div>

<div id="boxC"><div>
```

should be

```
<div id="boxB"></div>

<div id="boxC"></div>
```

You were opening new divs instead of closing them as you intended. Faced with three opening divs in a row, the browser built new divs so that `#boxC` was inside a box without id which was inside `#boxB`, then it closed them all when it got to the end of your html markup and couldn't find the closing tags it was waiting for.

As for `#boxB` (and now `#boxC`) overflowing `#main`, the problem is that you've set them to be 100% of their parent's height, but also included another div which takes up vertical space (that being `#boxA`). There are many solutions to this, but the easiest may be to decrease the height of `boxB` and `boxC` to account for the vertical space taken up by `#boxA`.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the code but both div's are still breaking through the main box. Any ideas?